# Laravel routing for a model with more than one key as the primary key

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

My model has company_id and employee_id as the primary key.

Normally, we use `/company/01/edit` to edit the company. But how the routing should be for employee? Both company_id and employee_id have to be in the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify you own way to represent a compound primary key in your url e.g.

`/company/01+aa/edit`

`/company/key1=01&key2=aa/edit`

`/company/x01qaa/edit`

`/company/01/employee_id/02/edit`

Comment: I had the same idea as you suggested and wanted to know whether is there an 'agreed' way of doing it. I would use something like `/employee/C01&E01/edit`

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, but you should note that I'm not the api specification boss of the internet :)

Comment: but it helped me :)